# Ionic app on ios Xcode error : API error: _UIKBCompatInputView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ionic-framework

I have built an ionic mobile app and running on ios using Xcode , the build is successful , the app is launched , on entering or clicking in input field on login page , following error is displayed on Xcode's console:
2023-05-03 17:00:17.860131+0530 App[68149:1345698] API error: <_UIKBCompatInputView: 0x1438132a0; frame = (0 0; 0 0); layer = <CALayer: 0x600002150620>> returned 0 width, assuming UIViewNoIntrinsicMetric

After adding input , on clicking login button , nothing is happening. Following are the versions which I am using :
"@capacitor/core": "2.0.0",
"@capacitor/ios": "^2.2.0",
"@ionic/cli": "^7.0.1",
"ionic": "^5.4.16"

How to fix these errors ?

I have checked the view UI hierarchy but did'nt find anything.